# Help with the sort command (numeric)

Tags: sort

I have this output I'd like to sort numerically by port (starting at the 35th column):

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.210:110       0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  3385/dovecot
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.210:143       0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  3385/dovecot
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.210:22        0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  2223/sshd
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.210:25        0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  3589/master
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.210:443       0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  2037/apache
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.210:587       0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  3589/master
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.210:80        0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  2037/apache
#                                 ^
#                                 Sorted at this column (#35)
```

So that the new output looks like this (lowest port first):

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.210:22        0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  2223/sshd
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.210:25        0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  3589/master
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.210:80        0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  2037/apache
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.210:110       0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  3385/dovecot
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.210:143       0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  3385/dovecot
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.210:443       0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  2037/apache
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.210:587       0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  3589/master
#                                 ^
#                                 Sorted at this column (#35)
```

I've played around with all different forms of `|sort`, including:

```
|sort -n         # <- I thought this would work
|sort -nk35
|sort -nk35,37
```

Etcetera, etcetera. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the purpose of the `-k` flag? Or maybe those colons are messing things up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sort` expects whitespace separated fields. To get it to sort on the port, you should change the field separator:

```
sort -t: -nk2 file
```

Here, I am telling `sort` to take `:` as the field separator. Therefore the first characters of the second field are the port number and it sorts as you want it to:

```
$ sort -t: -nk2 file
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.210:22        0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  2223/sshd
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.210:25        0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  3589/master
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.210:80        0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  2037/apache
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.210:110       0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  3385/dovecot
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.210:143       0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  3385/dovecot
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.210:443       0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  2037/apache
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.210:587       0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  3589/master
```

Comment: Aaahh! I thought `-k` was the overall column. Great, thanks!

Comment: @Jeff `-k` _is_ the column, however the columns are defined by the field separator.